# find a closed curve with given winding numbers

Tags: plane-curves, winding-number

Is there a closed (piecewise) $C^1$ curve $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, so that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma([a,b])$ has four components with winding numbers -1, 0, 2, 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution (see graphics below), $\gamma([a,b])$ is the concatenation of three (or better said four) circles:

The circuit begins in $B$, describes **twice** the circle with center $C$, then describes the circle with center $D$, all of them with a positive orientation, then, arriving back in $B$, describes the circle with center $A$ in the negative direction.

Here is a parameterization with $a=0, b=4$: 
$$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}
-2+2e^{2i \pi t}& (0 \leq t<2)\\
-1+e^{2i \pi t}& (2 \leq t <3)\\
2-2e^{-2i \pi t}& (3 \leq t <4)
                \end{cases}$$

(thanks to @Daniel Fischer
who has detected a bug in these intervals)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thanks. Two questions: 1) Is there a possibility without two loops on a circle? And 2) can you give a parametrisation?

Comment: 1) No, as you have a sudden jump from 2 to 0 without having a '+1" region, you have to use this "trick" (using twice the same loop). 2) OK for the parametrization, I am going to give it in my text.

Comment: In your parameterization: The intervall for the circles with center D and A are the same (=1). Is that right? You don't use the circle with center A twice?

Comment: Yes, this means that the arcs are not described at the same speed, but it doesn't matter.